# How to remove "Zend\ServiceManager\Exception\ServiceNotFoundException" error in zend framework

Tags: php, zend-framework

We created a function in controller file and when we are running that function in the browser, we are getting

> "Zend\ServiceManager\Exception\ServiceNotFoundException" error. Our controller file code is

```
public function indexAction()
{


    if (! $this->getServiceLocator()
             ->get('AuthService')->hasIdentity()){
        return $this->redirect()->toRoute('login');
    }

    return new ViewModel();
}
```

Any idea about this error?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, judging by the code you posted, this is Zend Framework 2 NOT Zend Framework 1.

You are getting this error because you are directly calling a service with the name `AuthService`, but that service doesn't exists. (There are plenty of reasons for this).

To solve your problem do this. First check to see if service exists.

```
//... more code

    if ($this->getServiceLocator()->has('AuthService')) {
        $auth = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('AuthService')->hasIdentity()
        if (!$auth) {
            return $this->redirect()->toRoute('login');
        }
        // code if user identity exists
    }

    return new ViewModel();
}
```